# Custom shell script to kill uWSGI by pid

Tags: shell, centos, sh, uwsgi

I'm to write a script which will grab all the text from a file (`/tmp/pidfile.txt`) which is just a pid number, and then store that as a variable (say `pidvar`) or something and execute the following:

```
kill -2 pidvar
```

Seems simple enough I just don't know how to grab the pid from the .txt file. I have python installed if this helps. Trying to make it easier to kill uWSGI, any suggestions on an alternative would be welcome.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal answer to your question (using a bash extension to be slightly more efficient) would be

```
kill -2 "$(</tmp/pidfile.txt)"
```

...or, to be compatible with POSIX sh but slightly less efficient...

```
kill -2 "$(cat /tmp/pidfile.txt)"
```

...but don't do it either of those ways.

---

pidfiles are prone to race conditions, whereas process-tree-based supervision systems can guarantee that they only ever deliver a signal to the correct process.

[runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), [systemd](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd), and many other alternatives are available which will guarantee that there's no risk of sending a signal to the wrong process based on stale data. CentOS is probably the last major operating system that *doesn't* ship with one of these (though future versions will almost certainly use systemd), but they're available as third-party packages -- and if you want your system to be reliable (detecting unexpected failures and restarting services as soon as they go down, for instance, without having to do it with your own code), you should be using one of them.

For instance, with systemd:

```
systemctl kill -s SIGINT uwsgi.service
```

...or, with runit:

```
sv interrupt uwsgi
```

...whereas with upstart, you can configure a completely arbitrary restart command to be triggered on `initctl reload uwsgi`.

---

For general best-practices documentation on using shell scripts for process management, see the appropriate page on [the wooledge.org wiki, maintained by irc.freenode.org's #bash channel](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful response. I am going to go with runit, this will make things much easier and my system more reliable. I am def a newbie here and appreciate your direction. (I would vote up your answer but I dont have enough rep)

Comment: @EVAunit01 I'm glad this helped! While it doesn't include a stock run script for uwsgi, the page at http://smarden.org/runit/runscripts.html should help you get started (and as you can see, run scripts are almost always just a line or two -- much easier than init scripts). By the way, even if you can't upvote, you can probably mark an answer accepted (and typically, doing so is worth a few reputation points in and of itself).

Answer (score 0):

It is generally easier to ask uwsgi to kill itself.  You can do this by using the "master-fifo" option in your config, and then send a "q" to the fifo.  This is described here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/MasterFIFO.html.